# Parse.com - Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: javascript, firefox, parse-platform, cross-domain, squarespace

I'm new to parse and javascript.  i'm going through a very simple tutorial at Parse.com (https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/new) and created the following block of code.  It works on chrome and IE but not safari or firefox. I got the cross-origin request blocked error on firefox.  Could you please help?

Firefox Error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.parse.com/1/classes/things. 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

My Code:

var PARSE_APP = "XXX";
var PARSE_JS = "XXX";

$(document).ready(function () {

```
Parse.initialize(PARSE_APP, PARSE_JS);

$("#FinishQuiz").click(function () {

    var ShoulderStrap = "";
    if ($("#ShoulderStrap1").prop("checked"))
    { ShoulderStrap = "1" }
    if ($("#ShoulderStrap2").prop("checked"))
    { ShoulderStrap = "2" }
    if ($("#ShoulderStrap3").prop("checked"))
    { ShoulderStrap = "3" }

    NoteObject = Parse.Object.extend("things");
    var object = new NoteObject();

    object.save({ ShoulderStrap: ShoulderStrap }).then(function (object) {
        alert("yay! it worked");
    });

});
```